# OpenLayers 6 - disable event listener from map

Tags: angular, events, listener, openlayers

How to disable the click event on the map? I'm trying to use map.un but it doesn't work. unByKey doesn't work

```
import unByKey
'unByKey' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
Module '"/node_modules/@types/ol/Observable/index"' has no exported member 'unByKey'
```

Try it with a checkbox, the event is added to the map, but when I uncheck the checkbox and check the checkbox, it is duplicated

```
function onClickDetail(evt) {
      console.log('Done');
};

    if (isCheck) 
    {
      map.on('singleclick',onClickDetail);
    }
    else
    {
      map.un('singleclick',onClickDetail);
    }
```

after 5 time reactivate checkbox

[image: 1]

Comment: can you show a bit more of your code? e.g. the ```map``` variable and the function where the if/else is in.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/50D4Nl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the function `onClickDetail` outside of your function `AddWMSLayer`. Otherwise it will always be a new function "pointer" and the reference will be not the same.

Comment: One question, there is no method that reset map to default state?

Comment: not that I know of. But im not an expert at OpenLayers at all.